# org.assertj.core.api.ObjectAssert.usingRecursiveComparison() Configuration Isn't Used for Child Objects

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-spanner, assertj

Our team is building a web service with Kotlin and Springboot that uses Google Cloud Spanner as a datastore.

Spanner has this cool feature called [commit timestamps](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/commit-timestamp) that records the time at which a row is committed to the database in a specified column.

The problem with this feature is that it makes it difficult to write unit tests. In particular, I'd like to write at test that looks like this:

```
@Test
fun saveAndLoadTest() {
    val id = UUID.randomUuid().toString()
    val expected = Foo(id)
    dao.save(expected)

    val actual = dao.load(id)
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

but this doesn't work if `Foo` has a field that is populated by Spanner's commit timestamp, because that field will differ when `actual` is compared to `expected`.

```
@Table("Foo")
data class Foo (

    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,

    // the value of this field will differ before and after the object is written to the database
    @Column(spannerCommitTimestamp = true)
    val createdTimestamp: Timestamp = Timestamp.now()
)
```

To get around this, I wrote an extension function that configures the way that the two instances of `Foo` are compared. It looks something like this:

```
fun <T> ObjectAssert<T>.isEqualIgnoringTimestamps(other: T): ObjectAssert<T> {
    this.usingRecursiveComparison()
        .ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes("createdTimestamp.*")
        .isEqualTo(other)
    return this
}
```

If I update the unit test to use my extension function, the assertion passes because any field whose name starts with `createdTimestamp` will be ignored:

```
@Test
fun saveAndLoadTest() {
    val id = UUID.randomUuid().toString()
    val expected = Foo(id)
    dao.save(expected)

    val actual = dao.load(id)

    // at this point, we're basically only checking that the `id` fields are the same
    assertThat(actual).isEqualIgnoringTimestamps(expected)
}
```

That's great, but it seems that the `org.assertj.core.api.ObjectAssert.usingRecursiveComparison()` configuration isn't used for child objects. This means that if I complicate `Foo` a little bit, the extension function stops working:

```
@Table("Foo")
data class Foo (

    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,

    // the "recursive" comparison rules won't be applied to this child object
    val child: Foo,

    @Column(spannerCommitTimestamp = true)
    val createdTimestamp: Timestamp = Timestamp.now()
)
```

Now the unit test fails with an error message that looks like this:

```
Expecting:
  <Foo(id=adfsikp87r6yu0hwy4pyg8oi9, child=Foo(id=cs6ne8m8tilcbhxq3s4ejxn5n, child=null, createdTimestamp=2021-06-18T20:08:37.142614000Z), createdTimestamp=2021-06-18T20:08:37.142614000Z)>
to be equal to:
  <Foo(id=adfsikp87r6yu0hwy4pyg8oi9, child=Foo(id=cs6ne8m8tilcbhxq3s4ejxn5n, child=null, createdTimestamp=2021-06-18T20:08:37.352000000Z), createdTimestamp=2021-06-18T20:08:37.352000000Z)>
when recursively comparing field by field, but found the following difference:

field/property 'child' differ:
- actual value   : Foo(id=cs6ne8m8tilcbhxq3s4ejxn5n, child=null, createdTimestamp=2021-06-18T20:08:37.352000000Z)
- expected value : Foo(id=cs6ne8m8tilcbhxq3s4ejxn5n, child=null, createdTimestamp=2021-06-18T20:08:37.142614000Z)

The recursive comparison was performed with this configuration:
- the fields matching the following regexes were ignored in the comparison: createdTimestamp.*
- these types were compared with the following comparators:
  - java.lang.Double -> DoubleComparator[precision=1.0E-15]
  - java.lang.Float -> FloatComparator[precision=1.0E-6]
- actual and expected objects and their fields were compared field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type, this allows for example to compare a Person to a PersonDto (call strictTypeChecking(true) to change that behavior).
```

The problem here appears to be that the `child.createdTimestamp` fields are not being ignored during the comparison, even though I've told the comparator to ignore fields called `createdTimestamp`. They are, of course, being ignored at the top level - just not in the child object.

Note that the same problem occurs if I tweak the recursive comparison configuration to ignore fields based on object type instead of name:

```
fun <T> ObjectAssert<T>.isEqualIgnoringTimestamps(other: T): ObjectAssert<T> {
    this.usingRecursiveComparison()
        .ignoringFieldsOfTypes(Timestamp::class.java)
        .isEqualTo(other)
    return this
}
```

Either way, the `createdTimestamp` field is ignored in the having object, but is not ignored in the has-a object.

So, with all of that explanation out of the way: What should I do about this problem?

- Is there a better way to configure the recursive comparison such that the configuration is applied to child objects (I would have thought that to be the case because it's supposed to be **recursive**, but I guess I was wrong)?
- Is there a better pattern to use in unit tests when making use of commit timestamps? I guess I could override the `.equals(...)` and `.hashCode()` methods on `Foo` such that the `createdTimestamp` field is ignored, but then I'm leaking test code into production code and that makes me feel icky

**tl;dr:** My database populates a created timestamp on my object at commit time. This makes it tricky to write unit tests because the object is changed when it is saved. How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue comes from a combination of two things:

- using an an old version of AssertJ that does not ignore overridden equals by default in the recursive comparison
- not using the right regex

The error shows that the `child` fields were not equal, this indicates to me that your `Foo` class has an overridden `equals` method (likely from being a data class) and that you are using an AssertJ Core version < 3.17.0 as from [3.17.0](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-3-17-0-release-notes) even if a class has overridden `equals` the recursive comparison would not use it and would compare its fields (note that by default root objects are always compared field by field).
If you are stuck with your old version simply use [ignoringAllOverriddenEquals](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.20.1/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringAllOverriddenEquals()).

Then the second issue is your regex is not doing what you expect it should do, instead of `createdTimestamp.*`, try `.*createdTimestamp`.

Why is that? Fields are expressed by their location from the root object (i.e the object under test) so when you specify `createdTimestamp.*` it means any  fields of the root **object** starting with `createdTimestamp`, it does not mean any `createdTimestamp` fields.

In your example it matches `Foo.createdTimestamp` as `Foo` is the root type being compared but it does not match `Foo.child.createdTimestamp`, to ignore the latter, you must specify `child\.createdTimestamp` (`\.` is for the regex not to interpret `.` as any character).

This does not really solve your issue because now `child.child.createdTimestamp` is not ignored but this is where regex are handy, `.*createdTimestamp` would do the job since it means: "any field location ending with `createdTimestamp`".

The related documentation is here:

- https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-fields
- https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(java.lang.String...)

I guess the documentation could show more examples of field regex usage and how they are interpreted. WDYT?

Comment: Updating the `.ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(...)` to use `.*createdTimestamps.*` and adding a `.ignoringAllOverriddenEquals()` seems to have solved the problem. As an aside, I noticed that the regex was getting cached, and that I had to do a clean/rebuild to get the test case to make use of the updated value. Thanks!